# Can I buy more than 2TB of storage on pCloud?

Tags: online-storage

Space on my QNAP NAS is running out. I'm taking some photos and videos, and I need to have space to store them, but I also want them accessible via a simple user-friendly interface (a virtual disk in Windows, like pCloud).

Problem is, I have 3TB of data, and it is growing. pCloud officially offers 2TB lifetime storage for a one-time price.

Can I buy two (or more) of the same, and expect **a single** 4TB cloud storage drive?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I have 4TB with pcloud. Get in touch and discuss it on their site - https://www.pcloud.com/company/contactus.html . I baulked at the cost, but it's for life, right? Uploading the data took me weeks a couple of years ago - literally weeks using the synch feature, but they have a new backup function that apparently speeds this up.